# .NET Standard 2.0 Xamarin.iOS project VSTS build issue

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, .net-standard-2.0

Currently I'm trying to upgrade a Xamarin.Forms project to use .NET Standard 2.0. This went fine for Android but I'm getting stuck with the iOS version. To build iOS we use a On-Primise MacMini as build agent int VSTS. Now I'm getting the error below when building the solution.

=================================

.... way more erros like below ...

2017-11-21T11:39:43.8920830Z   ViewModels/DashboardViewModel.cs(66,35): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. [/Users/Admin/BuildAgent/_work/3/s/xxx.App/xxx.Core.csproj]
2017-11-21T11:39:43.9014700Z   ViewModels/DashboardViewModel.cs(66,73): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. [/Users/Admin/BuildAgent/_work/3/s/xxx.App/xxx.Core.csproj]
2017-11-21T11:39:43.9036150Z   ViewModels/DashboardViewModel.cs(66,93): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. [/Users/Admin/BuildAgent/_work/3/s/xxx.App/xxx.Core.csproj]
2017-11-21T11:39:43.9053280Z 
2017-11-21T11:39:43.9083060Z     6 Warning(s)
2017-11-21T11:39:43.9107960Z     47 Error(s)
2017-11-21T11:39:43.9116100Z 
2017-11-21T11:39:43.9131830Z Time Elapsed 00:00:59.23
2017-11-21T11:39:43.9327960Z ##[error]Xamarin.iOS task failed with error Error: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/msbuild failed with return code: 1. For guidance on setting up the build definition, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=760847.
2017-11-21T11:39:43.9575950Z [command]/usr/bin/security delete-keychain /Users/Admin/BuildAgent/_work/3/s/_xamariniostasktmp.keychain
2017-11-21T11:39:44.2658340Z ##[section]Finishing: Build Xamarin.iOS solution xxx.sln

=================================

This output comes from the following build definition:

[image: CI Builddefinition]

Now I've searched the internet and found a view possible solutions:

- Update Visual Studio on the MacMini
- Update XCode on the MacMini
- Install .NET Core 2.x SDK on the MacMini
- Add .NET Standard 2.x NuGet package to Xamarin.IOS project
- Add .NET Standard Library NuGet pre-release package to Xamarin.iOS project (not possible)
- Manually reference netstandard.dll to the Xamarin.iOS project
- Remove install argument (not using it)

But all of this was not enough to fix the issue. Now I'm not a expert in using a Mac. Actually I never touched one before this issue... So I might have done something wrong here...

But I've been able to get some version information about all products on the MacMini:

========= Visual Studio =========

Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac
Version 7.2.2 (build 11)
Installation UUID: b43353ef-651c-468b-8b7d-3f1714586419
Runtime:
Mono 5.4.1.6 (2017-06/1f4613aa1ac) (64-bit)
GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

Package version: 504010006

NuGet
Version: 4.3.1.4445

.NET Core
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Version: 2.0.3
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.3/Sdks
SDK Version: 2.0.3
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.5.6
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Xamarin.Android
Not Installed

Xamarin Inspector
Not Installed

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 9.1 (13532)
Build 9B55

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 11.3.0.47 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 51128b8c
Branch: xcode9.1
Build date: 2017-10-31 22:42:13-0400

Xamarin.Mac
Xamarin.Mac not installed. Can't find /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/Version.

Build Information
Release ID: 702020011
Git revision: b604c37c5a4a2f0919b45ffbe2aaad9fe040af31
Build date: 2017-11-01 08:31:43-04
Xamarin addins: d57dc14cbd4eb166ee62bab585965ab78d3650bc
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-d15-4

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.12.6
Darwin 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0
    Wed Oct  4 00:17:00 PDT 2017
    root:xnu-3789.71.6~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

============= XCode =============

XCode for Mac 
Version 9.1 (9B55)

============= Mono ==============

Mono JIT compiler version 5.4.1.6 (2017-06/1f4613aa1ac Wed Oct 18 09:31:57 EDT 2017)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
TLS:           normal
SIGSEGV:       altstack
Notification:  kqueue
Architecture:  amd64
Disabled:      none
Misc:          softdebug 
LLVM:          yes(3.6.0svn-mono-master/8b1520c8aae)
GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)

========= .NET Core SDK =========

.NET Core SDK
Version 2.0.3

=================================

The project can be build on the MacMini itself. Only the VSTS task keeps failing...

Does someone have any idea's left which can help me solve my issue?

Kind regards,
Jop

Comment: Where did you created the app, on windows OS or Mac? And what's the project type, is it Xamarin.Forms class library on windows or iso App in mac VS? And can you share the project in one drive. Besides, there has a related issue https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/391, you can check if it helps.

Comment: Hi @MarinaLiu-MSFT, I've already seen the post you've provided but it didn't provide me with an answer. But we've been able to solve the issue in the meantime. I'll post the answer shortly. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything started to work fine after we manually edited the .NET Standard 2.0 project file (*.csproj) and add a PackageReference by hand.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  ...
  <PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library" version="2.0.0" />
  ...
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: You can mark it as answer. And it will benefit others who have similar questions.

Comment: Forgot to mark it. Thanks for the reminder @MarinaLiu-MSFT

Comment: If you do this, a warning in the build logs will pop up that this reference should not be added: warning : A PackageReference for 'NETStandard.Library' was included in your project. This package is implicitly referenced by the .NET SDK and you do not typically need to reference it from your project. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicitrefs

Comment: I'm facing same issues i have followed the same  but did not fixed it.##[error]Xamarin.iOS task failed with error Error: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/msbuild failed with return code: 1., see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=760847.